# Trigger on PermissionSet or PublicGroup possible ? Or way to crack it

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, permission-sets, public-group

We want to fetch the permission set and public group info into custom object.
We run batch to do that(Scheduled every day). So we need to wait for a day to get the latest. Now we want to reduce those time.

Is there a way trigger on `Permission Set` or `Public Group`? Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can not write trigger on Permision set or groups.What you can do is you can query on object 'PermissionSet'  and copy those value to your object.Eg - SELECT Id,Name,PermissionsViewAllData FROM PermissionSet

Answer (score 1):

You can run a batch much more frequently than every day. I've run them as frequently as every 15 minutes without issue by calling `System.scheduleBatch` in the `finish` method. You should probably add some sort of `Boolean` flag to control chaining for ease of testing, and you wish to control that flag via `Hierarchy Custom Setting`. The basic idea is simply:

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    @TestVisible Boolean chainBatches = true;

    // implementation

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        if (chainBatches)
            system.scheduleBatch(this, 'MyBatch ' + Datetime.now().format(), 15);
    }
}
```